# C++ DLL imported into a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to do a basic C++ DLL in order to use it in C#.. the following classes are used:

My cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include "MathFuncsAssembly.h"

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw gcnew DivideByZeroException("b cannot be zero!");
        }

        return a / b;
    }
}
```

My header file

```
using namespace System;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    public ref class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        static double Add(double a, double b);

        static double Subtract(double a, double b);

        static double Multiply(double a, double b);

        static double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

and in my C# application where I am invoking the library

```
[DllImport("MathFuncsAssembly.dll")]
public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine(Add(10.0, 11.0));
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

An exception occurs at the (Add(10.0,11.0)) part.. The following exception is being thrown:
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B).. Any Ideas? Also, i copied the .dll file in the bin of the c# application...

thanks!

Comment: is the DLL file 32 or 64 bit? is your clr 32 or 64 bit? usually it's this type of incompatibility associated with your error.

Comment: you are doing this the wrong way.. if you have a ref class (and hence a C++/CLI dll), you don't need DllImport at all: just add a reference to the dll in the C# project and call the functions 'the C# way' i.e. MathFuncs.Add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a ref class (and hence a C++/CLI dll), you don't need DllImport at all: just add a reference to the dll in the C# project and call the functions 'the C# way' i.e. `MathFuncs.Add()` (note you still need to make sure the platform matches, and that all native dlls the CLI dll depends on are in the path)

Comment: @stijin.. my application consists of struct.. where shall I define the struct ? in the header or the .cpp? Also, some methods returns a pointer to an instance of the struct.. how can i do that ? because i keep getting the same error over and over.. the error is the following: 'Error 27 error C2027: use of undefined type '

Comment: normally you'd declare the struct with it's functions in the header and provide definitions in the source (cpp). C2027 means you are using a type the compiler does not know.. Better start a seperate question for this and post code, else it's impossible to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you are trying to use a x32 DLL with a x64 program or viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

"Incorrect format" exceptions always mean that you're loading a module compiled for a different platform i.e. 32 vs 64 bit. Make sure your DLL and your C# app are compiled for the same platform. If C# is set for "Any platform" select explicitly the one that your DLL is for.